# Extraer Coincidencias de 2 listas en base a 1 lista y crear una nueva lista

Tags: python-3.x, paso-por-valor

Soy nuevo en python y estoy intentando crear un lista tipo string, en base a los ingresos de 3 listas de de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
sin embargo al intentar imprimirlas no me muestra la salida como la de la imagen. Ya que en la lista Ganadora hay valores que se encuentran en la lista de Alejandro y Carolina, Debería Imprimirme cada coincidencia con una letra "E" de empate, pero mi código solo me muestra la última. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme diciéndome que debo corregir o que debo agregar? Muchas gracias.

```
# Declarar las escuderias favoritas de Alejandro y Carolina Respectivamente.
escuderias_fav_alejandro = "RAIFZ"
escuderias_fav_carolina = "UZEOF"

ingreso_esc_fav_alejandro = input("Ingrese la lista de escuderías favoritas de Alejandro:\n")  

ingreso_esc_fav_carolina = input("Ingrese la lista de escuderías favortias de Carolina: \n")

ingreso_ganadores_tempo = input("Ingrese los ganadores de la temporada: ")
posibles_ganadoras = ingreso_ganadores_tempo

for i in ingreso_esc_fav_alejandro:
    for j in ingreso_ganadores_tempo:
        if(i==j):
            print("A", end="")
            break

for k in ingreso_esc_fav_carolina:
    for j in ingreso_ganadores_tempo:
        if(k==j) and i:
            print("C" , end="")
            break

for j in i and k:
    print("E", end="")
    break
```

Comment: las condiciones que se plantea en el problema son muy confusas :/

Comment: @Christian ya puse el problema, completo

Comment: no te preocupes ya lo entendí, en un momento te doy una respuesta

Comment: @Christian intenté corregirlo así, pero ahora solo me imprime 6 Letras, creo que tengo que agregar un contador pero no sé en que parte colocarlo.           `for j in ingreso_ganadores_tempo:
    if(j in ingreso_esc_fav_alejandro):
        print("A", end="")
    elif(j in ingreso_esc_fav_carolina):
        print("C", end="")
    elif(j in ingreso_esc_fav_carolina and ingreso_esc_fav_alejandro):
        print("E") `

Comment: solo necesitas un ciclo :/, espera a mi respuesta

Comment: @Christian Entiendo Muchas Gracias. Yo espero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema te dice que cada participante va a tener algunas letras que le darán puntos, si la letra esta **solamente** en un participante se le suma un punto al participante, si esta en **ambos** se le suma un punto a ambos, si **no esta en ninguno** no se le suma puntos a nadie, y luego se tiene que estar verificando en cada *turno* quien es el ganador. Tu utilizas *innecesariamente* 2 ciclos `for` pero en realidad solo se necesita 1, esto ya que tenemos la hermosa sintaxis de verificar si un elementos esta en otro con `x in list` se puede verificar si un elemento esta en una lista o también se puede verificar si un caracter esta en un string `"A" in string`, dado que siempre se tiene que estar verificando al ganador, crearé una función que se encargue de determinar al ganador de acuerdo al punta. También usare un diccionario como estructura de dato, esto para tener los datos mas ordenados dado que se tiene que almacenar el puntaje de ambos.

**función para determinar ganador**

```py
def winner(puntos_a,puntos_c):
    #si los puntos de alejandro es mayor que los de carolina
    if puntos_a>puntos_c: 
        return "A" #gana alejandro
    elif puntos_a==puntos_c: #si son iguales
        return "E" #empate
    else: #de lo contrario
        return "C" #gana carolina
```

**diccionario con participantes**

```py
participantes = {"Alejandro":{"fav":"RAIFZ", "puntos":0}, "Carolina":{"fav":"UZEOF","puntos":0}}

#con inputs
#fav_alejandro = input("Ingrese las favoritas de alejandro: ")
#fav_carolina = input("Ingrese las favoritas de carolina: ")
#participantes = {"Alejandro":{"fav": fav_alejandro , "puntos":0}, "Carolina":{"fav": fav_carolina,"puntos":0}}
```

**código principal**

Como dije, solo utilizaremos un ciclo `for` para iterar en los ganadores de la carrera.

```py
#ganadores_carrera  = input("Ingrese los ganadores de la carrera: ")
ganadores_carrera = "IHZOWFEI"

#accedemos a los participantes, esto para no escribir tanto
alejandro = participantes["Alejandro"] 
carolina = participantes["Carolina"]

#accedemos a los favoritos del participante, igual para no escribir tanto
fav_alejandro = alejandro["fav"]
fav_carolina = carolina["fav"]

for g in ganadores_carrera:
    #si la letra solo esta en alejandro
    if g in fav_alejandro and g not in fav_carolina:
        alejandro["puntos"]+=1 #sumamos un punto
        #comprobamos ganador
        #agregamos end="" para que se muestre en horinzontal
        print(winner(alejandro["puntos"],carolina["puntos"]),end="") #le pasamos los puntos de ambos
    #si la letra solo esta en carolina
    elif g in fav_carolina and g not in fav_alejandro:
        carolina["puntos"]+=1 #sumamos un punto
        #verificamos al ganador
        print(winner(alejandro["puntos"],carolina["puntos"]),end="") 
    #si esta en ambos
    elif g in fav_alejandro and g in fav_carolina:
        #sumamos un punto a cada uno
        carolina["puntos"]+=1 
        alejandro["puntos"]+=1
        #comprobamos al ganador
        print(winner(alejandro["puntos"],carolina["puntos"]),end="")
    #si no esta en ninguno
    elif g not in fav_alejandro and g not in fav_carolina:
        #comprobamos al ganador
        print(winner(alejandro["puntos"],carolina["puntos"]),end="")
```

**resultado**

```
AAAEEECE
```

En caso lo quieras hacer con contadores, tendríamos que declara un contador para cada participante, para este caso hare el código sin usar un diccionario

```py
#delcaramos las variables
fav_alejandro = "RAIFZ"
fav_carolina = "UZEOF"
ganadores_carrera = "IHZOWFEI"

#con inputs
# fav_alejandro = input("Ingrese las favoritas de alejandro: ")
# fav_carolina = input("Ingrese las favoritas de carolina: ")
# ganadores_carrera = input("Ingrese los ganadores")
```

La función para determinar al ganador se quedará igual. Ahora en vez de sumar 1 al valor del diccionario lo haremos al contador del participante, lo mismo para obtener el valor.

```
#iniciamos los puntos con 0
points_alejandro = 0
points_carolina = 0

for g in ganadores_carrera:
    #si la letra solo esta en alejandro
    if g in fav_alejandro and g not in fav_carolina:
        points_alejandro+=1
        #verifiacmos al ganador
        print(winner(points_alejandro,points_carolina),end="") #end="" para que se muestre horizontal
    #si la letra solo esta en carolina
    elif g in fav_carolina and g not in fav_alejandro:
        points_carolina+=1
        print(winner(points_alejandro,points_carolina),end="")
    #si esta en ambos
    elif g in fav_alejandro and g in fav_carolina:
        #sumamos el punto a ambos
        points_carolina+=1
        points_alejandro+=1
        #verifiacmos al ganador
        print(winner(points_alejandro,points_carolina),end="")
    #si no esta en ninguno
    elif g not in fav_alejandro and g not in fav_carolina:
        #verifiacmos al ganador
        print(winner(points_alejandro,points_carolina),end="")
```

utilicé contadores tal y como me pediste en los comentarios, si no deseas utilizar diccionarios y prefieres hacerlo de esta forma no hay problema, solo que esto también se puede resumir usando otra estructura de dato como listas `[]` o tuplas `()`  o una mezcla de ambos, una lista de tuplas `[(participante1,point),(participante2,points)]`. Te dejo eso para que juegues y aprendas más :D

Comment: Tu respuesta está muy bien detallada y está excelente, pero el programa especificamente me pide que ingrese los datos de las carreras de Alejandro y Carolina y adicional a eso que ingrese las carreras ganadas: y que el resultado sea mostrado en vertical. En la parte en donde está el diccionario solo habria que colocar input? para que muestre al usuario "Ingrese la favoritas de alejandro" "ingrese las favoritas  de Carolina" "ingrese las ganadoras de la temporada". y adicional para que me muestre el resultado en horizontal y no en vertical, ¿ qué podría hacer ahí?

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo, Ya lo modifiqué para que mostrará exactamente lo mismo que en la tabla, Pero sin embargo me gustaría saber como en vez de usar un diccionario se pudiera usar un contador... Quiero aprender y pues me gustaria saber en donde podria poner el contador. en vez del diccionario.

Comment: Ok en in momento modifco mi respuesta

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tu me fuiste de gran ayuda en mi aprendizaje el día de hoy. <3